# Pandas dataframe, empty or with 3 column to pickle

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm not used to pandas at all, thus the several question on my problem.

I have a function computing computing a list called `solutions`. This list can either be made of tuples of 3 values `(a, b, c)` or empty.

```
solutions = [(a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)]
```

To save it, I first turn it into a numpy array, and then I save it with pandas after naming the columns.

```
solutions = np.asarray(solutions)
df = pd.DataFrame(solutions)
df.columns = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
df.to_pickle(path)
```

My issue is that I sometimes have a empty solutions list: `solutions = []`. Thus, the line `df.columns` raises an error. To bypass it, I currently check the size of solutions, and if it is empty, I do:

```
pickle.dump([], path, "wb")
```

I would like to be a more consistent between my data type, and to save the SAME format between both scenario.
=> If the list is empty, I would like to save the 3 columns name with an empty data frame. Ultimate goal, is to reopen the file with `pd.read_pickle()` and to access easily the data in it.

Second issue, I would like to reopen the files pickled, and to add a column. Could you show me the right way to do so?

And third question, how can I select a part of the dataframe. For instance, I want all lines in which the column `Name1 value % 0.25 == 0`.

Thanks

Comment: Could you also provide the code that actually inserts the list `solutions` into the DataFrame `df`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Yep Edit done, I missed one line in the example, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your dataframe using:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=solutions, columns=['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])
```

If `solutions` is empty, it will nevertheless create a dataframe with 3 columns and 0 row.

```
In [2]: pd.DataFrame(data=[(1,2,3), (4,5,6)], columns=['a','b','c'])
Out[2]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(data=[], columns=['a','b','c'])
Out[3]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

Comment: Exactly what I was needing. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `np.asarray()`, see my edit (comments are not easy to format with code ;-)

Comment: Yep I noticed, that's why I deleted the comment... That's not straightforward thinking for me yet. Thanks.

Comment: But then is there a way to reload the data in the same way. Right now I'm doing `df = pd.read_pickle(path).values` which returns np.arrays of np.arrays... And It's pretty annoying to have list of tuple when I write, and arrays of arrays when I read :/

Comment: Pandas has a serie of convenient helpers to load/save using various file format. I usually rely on csv as it is easy to read them using a text editor. I would avoid to_pickle and read_pickle for compatibility reason and security reason (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-pickle for more information).
If your question is not about this, please open a new question on SO, as comments are not very convenient to discuss about it ;)

Comment: I know most people rely on csv, but it is not convenient nor efficient in my problem. My list solutions can be really large, or really small, and a serial way to store and access data is more efficient for me.
Anyway, it did answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your third question:

```
df["Name1"] % 0.25 == 0
```

computes a series of booleans which are true where the value in the first column can be divided by 0.25. You can use it to select the rows of your dataframe:

```
df[ df["Name1"] % 0.25 == 0 ]
```